# Matrix Multiplication where $A\times B = B\times A$

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

I am taking a CS class that involves *OpenGL* in *C++*, but we are going through some trig and I was stumped by a question on our test involving matrices and multiplication of matrices.

I'm going to be specific as possible but I can't remember the exact wording because it has been handed in so bear with me:

"Show me two $4\times4$ matrices ($M_1$ and $M_2$) where the rule $A\times B = B\times A$ is true for $M_1$ and $M_2$."

This teacher only discussed this rule briefly and certainly did not discuss cool exception to the rule.

Should $M_2$ be the inverse of $M_2$ in order for this to be true? Or could $M_1$ be anything and $M_2$ be the Identity Matrix?

Comment: Both things you describe sound like good examples!

Comment: Well, first you are asked when $AB=BA$, it immediately requires the matrices be $n\times n$. if $B = A^{-1}$, then a further requirement is that $A,B$ have to be invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrices $A = \left[ \matrix{1\ 0\ 0\ 0\\0\ 2\ 0\ 0\\0\ 0\ 3\ 0\\0\ 0\ 0\ 4 } \right]$ and $B = \left[ \matrix{4\ 0\ 0\ 0\\0\ 3\ 0\ 0\\0\ 0\ 2\ 0\\0\ 0\ 0\ 1 } \right]$. Then we have:

$AB=BA=\left[ \matrix{4\ 0\ 0\ 0\\0\ 6\ 0\ 0\\0\ 0\ 6\ 0\\0\ 0\ 0\ 4 } \right]$

It's actually very easy to come up with matrices that don't satisfy this property. (loosely speaking, there's more matrices satisfying $AB\neq BA$, than there are matrices satisfying $AB=BA$).

Comment: Thank you this is extremely helpful and what I was looking for. I was hurting my head thinking about it. He is going to go over the test tomorrow in class and I'm curious to see his accepted answers and how many other people understood this, unlike me. :-/

Answer (score 2):

A matrix will commute with any polynomial of itself.  If $f$ is a polynomial and $A$ is a square matrix, $f(A)$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: Adding details to your answer: For any matrix $A$ clear that $A^m$ and $A^n$ commute for any integers $m,n$. Also if $A$ commutes with $B$ and $C$ then it will also commute with $bB+cC$ for any scalars $b,c$.  That is how $f(A)$ always commutes with $A$.